# How to use a sitemap to generate an accordion menu?

Tags: javascript, xml

I use XHTML to author help documentation. The navigation menu is XML that's transformed into JavaScript and then loaded/displayed in the HTML as a nav menu using ul. This process creates generated content.

Is there a way I can generate a menu using a sitemap perhaps?

I'm good with HTML, CSS, and some JavaScript. I'm looking for some advice please.

Jim

- I've tried SmartMenus, but that's not capturing the submenu items.
- I've tried some simple JavaScript alternatives, and they aren't working.
- I'm not permitted to create an ID on the  element. I can apply a class, though.
- I've tried wrapping the ul in a div.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.